# Positive Spearman's r value with negative abline

Tags: r

I'm looking over some data I collected this week-end and one of the Spearman correlation test gave me a positive value, but when I add an abline on the plot, it is descending. I'm curious how this can be possible.

Here's are the data for Study:

```
    Year Matches Total
1   1958    2   7
2   1959    2   14
3   1960    5   9
4   1961    2   20
5   1962    4   27
6   1963    5   20
7   1964    5   25
8   1965    5   20
9   1966    3   18
10  1967    5   28
11  1968    6   26
12  1969    4   24
13  1970    6   22
14  1971    7   32
```

And here's the procedure I used:

```
Results<- (Study$Matches/Study$Total)*100
Year<-Study$Year
plot(Year, Results, main = "MAIN")
fit1 <- lm (Results ~ Year, data = Study)
abline(fit1, lty = "dashed")
cor.test(Year, Results, method = "s")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fit produces a linear model. Pearson is the linear correlation and it is negative. Spearman is non-linear and based on the ranking.

```
> cor.test(Year,Results,method="spearman")

Spearman's rank correlation rho

data:  Year and Results
S = 438.9647, p-value = 0.9048
alternative hypothesis: true rho is not equal to 0
sample estimates:
       rho 
0.03524238 

Warning message:
In cor.test.default(Year, Results, method = "spearman") :
  Cannot compute exact p-value with ties
> cor(Year,Results,method="spearman")
[1] 0.03524238
> cor(Year,Results,method="pearson")
[1] -0.17501
```

It is correctly plotting the negative linear correlation. It just happens that Spearman is positive. Unintuitive things can happen when correlations are low. The high p-value is a clue too.

Comment: Yep. OP should take a look at the results of `plot(rank(Results) ~ Year, data=Study); abline(lm(rank(Results) ~ Year, data=Study));`